# will Shimano Shimano Dura Ace 7700 STI Flight Deck work with Rear Derailleur Shimano XT RD-M771

Tags: compatibility

I thinking to change my Long Haul Trucker set up. Have both Dura Ace 7700 / 7703 STI Flight Deck 3x9. Will it be compatible with the LHT stock Front Derailleur Shimano Sora FD-3403 n Rear Derailleur Shimano XT RD-M771.

I'm changing over to Paul Touring Canti's brakes too. Just wondering what other issues might come up

Sorry if these questions are redundant. 
Thanks for your time and consideration.

Comment: Yes (it sounds like your LHT is a 9 speed one, so this should be fine).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all nominally 9-speed Shimano mountain RDs will work with ST-7700, and all pre-11-speed road FDs will work with ST-7703, except for FD-4700 at present and any future 10-or-fewer groups that use the 11-speed actuation ratio.